# attribute "saldo" does not change

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, oop

I'm training a restapi project with spring in java, I'm a beginner so sorry for the code.

[Well I'm creating a card where this card has the following constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxeHb.png)

[in another file I have my services, one of them is update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sunD4.png)

when I use the post to call my endpoint, all the data that I pass in my "updateData" json is updated, but the balance remains at 500. I don't know what else to do to successfully change the "saldo" field.

[here is my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YrtS.png)

[here is the upadte endpoint passing the fields that i am updating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWZQY.png)

[here is the endpoint find with the id I'm wanting to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z6RY.png)

[here is the updated id but with the balance still at 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmuqN.png)

Comment: please check [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C82.2111)

Answer (score 0):

The problem, you defined the value fix to saldo.

```java
public Cartao(...double saldo...){
[...]
this.saldo = saldo;
}
```

[image]